# Python pandas sample without mixing index

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I want to apply the [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) function from Pandas independently for each value of the index for a data frame. This can be done with a `for` loop like this:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'something': [3,4,2,2,6,7], 'n': [1,1,2,2,3,3]})
df.set_index(['n'], inplace=True)

resampled_as_I_want_df = df[0:0]
for i in sorted(set(df.index)):
    resampled_as_I_want_df = resampled_as_I_want_df.append(
        df.loc[i].sample(frac=1, replace=True),
    )

print(resampled_as_I_want_df)
```

Let me explain this in a human-friendly way. The `df` data frame looks like this:

```
   something
n           
1          3
1          4
2          2
2          2
3          6
3          7
```

Now we see that there are three "index groups" which have the values `1`, `2` and `3`. What I want to do is to apply the `sample` function in a way that the new data frame will have the same index, without random sampling, and the sampling is performed within each group as if they were independent data frames.

Is there a way to avoid the `for` loop? For large data frames it is a bottle neck.

Comment: But if you use `frac=1`, shouldnt your desired output look exactly like the input?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "**without** random sampling"? Do you want to sample each group or not?

Comment: WRT `frac=1`, no because I am `replace=True`. What I mean is that I want to apply the `sample` function to those subsets of the dataframe that have the same index, if they have different index I don't want to mix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.groupby(level=0).sample(frac=1, replace=True)`.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks.